# How can you allow an unregistered user to change languages?

Tags: 7, i18n-l10n

I have no clue to which is the Drupal way of allowing any user (registered or not) to change the website language.

The way I need it to work is to allow any user to click on their preferred language flag and just change the interface language.

What modules should I look into?
Is there any function I should be calling when clicking the flag?

Any link to something resembling a walktrough is also appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it's just the interface you'd like to translate, then I think you can get by with [Locale](http://drupal.org/documentation/modules/locale) (a core module). If you want content translation (and many other things) you can use [i18n](http://drupal.org/project/i18n). The project page for i18n gives you plenty of links to follow for other projects and documentation.

Comment: Thanks Andy, yes, I need only the interface translation, not the content. So I had it narrowed to Locale, but I still have no clue how to allow someone to change the language by clicking on a flag. Could you please shed some light?

Comment: @andre There's a language switcher block that comes with locale. Just enable that and theme it appropriately.

Answer (score 1):

You will probably also want to look at the [Language Icons](https://www.drupal.org/project/languageicons) module, which provides the flags. Some details about this module (from its project page):

> This module provides icons for language links, both for the Language switcher block and (optionally) for node links. It is a spin-off from Internationalization (i18n) package.
>
> As basic multilingual support is now built into Drupal 6 core, it doesn't depend anymore on any other contributed module. This module will work as simple add-in for Drupal 6.
>
> However, for a fully enabled multilingual site, the Internationalization package is recommended.

Setup is very important with localization. I suggest that you start -- preferably on a test site -- by setting Language negotiation to "Path prefix only" and Content selection mode to "Mixed current language (if available) or default language (if not) and language neutral"