# Which are the steps to make Locale language switcher block appear at selected area?

Tags: 7, i18n-l10n

After this question on [which module to use to handle interface translation](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/1899/how-can-you-allow-an-unregistered-user-to-change-languages) I was expecting the setup of Locale to be pretty straightforward. I guess it is not.

Well, my backend and navigation menus got translated right away but the main objective (as you can see by reading the other question) was to allow any user to change language as needed.

So the goal is to setup the language switcher block in order that it is available to everyone.
Steps performed:

- Enable module Locale
- Setup language switcher block to appear at some area
- Configured block to appear to all roles on every page
- Added a new language and imported the .po file
- Checked all locale permissions (except anonymous user -> translation)

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the language negotiation.

Comment: Andy, once again, spot on! :-) Nice!

Answer (score 0):

I think the block only appears on pages which have translated content

Comment: Nope, that's not the case, and as I said, I've imported the .po file which translates most of the drupal core.

Comment: allright, i really should read questions more slowly ;) my bad

Comment: You are however not totally wrong. If you are using translation.module and you are on a node that is *not* translated in some languages, then these will not be displayed. See http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--locale--locale.module/function/locale_block/6 (note the drupal_alter) and http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--translation--translation.module/function/translation_translation_link_alter/6